# How to do this subtraction in Less?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

```
margin-top: (@xui-line-height-computed/2)-2px;
```

This is outputting **"10px -2px"**, instead of doing the arithmetic and outputting **"-8px"**

Comment: check if the variable @xui-line-height-computed is defined, the arithmetic operation works perfect, see the compiled and non compiled version of css in this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNOMyK

Comment: See [`--strict-math`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math) (it's off by default, but most likely you're using some project where it's on).